# Handling TypeError: 'NoneType' in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, exception, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I am scraping a webpage with BeautifulSoup and the line where I look for a csrf token sometimes throws a TypeError.

Code is:

```
csrf = soup.find(id="csrfToken-postModuleForm")['value']
```

The error returned is:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am looking to just continue with the script if that value does not exist instead of having the exception thrown - any idea how that is possible?

Comment: Just using `try` `except` blocks, and put a `pass` statement inside the except block. Mind you, it would completely skip over with it.

Comment: @Zizouz212  `except: pass` is a dangerous construction which hides fundamental bugs. It is a poor suggestion in general and even more so for neophytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
try:
    # Try to get the CSRF token
    csrf = soup.find(id="csrfToken-postModuleForm")['value']
except(TypeError, KeyError) as e:
    # Token not found. Replace 'pass' with additional logic.
    pass
```

Here, you can add any additional logic, such as:

```
    print("CSRF Not Found.")
```

Make sure you understand how CSRF tokens work. They're an important part of web security.

Comment: The soup.find is returning None not the lookup so this will again cause an error if value does not exist

Comment: I don't think you really get my point. what happens when you do find something and it has no value attribute? You do realise what `['value']` is doing?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the catch for the KeyError. I didn't understand your comment without punctuation.

Comment: The syntax will throw a syntax error on python 3 and is incorrect for python 2.

Comment: You would not learn much by me doing it for you. The `as e` is not necessary unless you actually plan on using it for logging etc..

Comment: Of course. I don't know what his additional logic will be. That is the same reason my answer was formatted for Python 2, since the error he received comes from Python 2, not Python 3. We've all learned something, now.

Comment: To amplify @PadraicCunningham if you cannot handle an exception in "Additional logic here" you ought not pretend that you can. An except clause which only (for example) logs an error, should end with "raise" instead of "pass" in order to re-raise the exception. The pass statement is the opposite of handling; it hides defects.

Comment: But not putting pass would surely result in an error without raising or writing that additional code. Pass should be replaced by that logic, and could raise if necessary. I will update the answer to clarify.